# Mismatch with match function in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have the above data in row 1 (i.e. cell A1, cell B1, cell C1, etc).

I want to find the column number of the cell that contains Apr 2013.

Here's my code:

```
MsgBox Application.Match("Apr 2013", Range("1:1"), 1)
```

which returns mismatch error. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Your error is because you need to use WorksheetFunction.Match instead of Application.Match. but @mehow's approach is better anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try this instead:

```
Sub main()
    Dim stringToMatch$
    stringToMatch = "Apr 2013"
    Call DisplayMatchingColumnNumber(ActiveSheet, stringToMatch)
End Sub

Sub DisplayMatchingColumnNumber(ByRef ws As Worksheet, str$)
Dim i&, x$
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        x = Right(CStr(ws.Cells(1, i).Value), 8)
        If StrComp(x, str, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "the column number is: " & i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

---

As [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx) says:

```
Arg2 is Required of type Variant 
Lookup_array - a contiguous range of cells containing possible lookup values. 
Lookup_array must be an array or an array reference.
```

Therefore:

```
Sub ReadAboutFunctionsYouAreUsing()
    Dim x
    x = Array("Apr 2013", "Mar 2013", "Feb 2013")
    MsgBox Application.Match("Apr 2013", x, 1)
End Sub
```

---

---

**User Defined Function**
in any cell type: `=getColumnNumber("Apr 2013")`

```
Function getColumnNumber(str$)
    Dim i&, x$
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        x = Right(CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value), 8)
        If StrComp(x, str, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            getColumnNumber = i
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Could this be converted to a function for general usage?

Comment: User defined function? to return number of column?

Comment: I modified the first code you wrote and it works. But, i would need to be able to use the value of i to extract other values.

Comment: in VBA - `Dim returnedValue&` then new line `returnedValue = getColumnNumber("Feb 2013")`

Answer (score 1):

I get this sort of thing in VBA a lot, especially with dates. Here's what I would do:

```
Dim tmpRng As Range
Set tmpRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AA:650") 'or some other unused cell
tmpRng.Value = "Apr 2013"
MsgBox Application.Match(tmpRng, Range("1:1"), 1)
tmpRng.Value = ""
```

For some reason, Match seems to like having a cell reference as its first parameter.